# Android: How do I undo a bitmap which has been drawn to a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, markers

I am dropping drawables on a canvas like markers, setting the final bitmap to an ImageView. How do I add an undo functionality where I can undo one drawable at a time? Please help.

This is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

//Create a new image bitmap and attach a brand new canvas to it
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

 Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

 //Draw the image bitmap into the canvas
 tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

 Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.check);

 //Draw into the canvas
 tempCanvas.drawBitmap(marker, x, y, null);

 //Attach the canvas to the ImageView
 imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at canvas.save() and canvas.restoreToCount(int)

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 That doesn't work. restore() removes all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save() call. I am adding bitmaps to the canvas, which probably isn't a matrix change. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a hack. I used an ArrayList to store the annotated bitmap after each drop of the marker. I just pop the last item from the list and display the new bitmap on undo. If anyone is interested, here is the code:

```
bitmapLayers.add(annotatedBitmap);
```

And for undo:

```
if (!bitmapLayers.isEmpty())
{
      bitmapLayers.remove(bitmapLayers.size() - 1);
      Bitmap last = bitmapLayers.get(bitmapLayers.size() - 1);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(last);

      //If no undos left, hide button
      if (bitmapLayers.size() == 1)
      {
          mUndo.setVisible(false);
      }
 }
```

It would be great if someone can provide an optimized solution.